# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: regeneratorRuntime on React

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm trying to creat a login with react and firebase. I've been following a tutorial, the problem is that this code:

```
const handleLogin = useCallback(
    async event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const { email, password } = event.target.elements;
        try {
            await firebaseConfig.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email.value, password.value);
            history.push("/citas")
        } catch (error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    },
    [history]
);
```

is giving me this error:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: regeneratorRuntime

I don't find any solution as I don't know what it means. Any ideas?

Comment: How do you know that it's the code you're showing here that's causing the problem?  What are you observing as you debug this?

Comment: Browser console said so.

Comment: How do you know it's this code?  What have you done to debug this?

Comment: It's fixed! Anyway as I said browser console said it was that line of code.

Comment: I understand about the console log.  On Stack Overflow, it's expected that the question give some context about what you're trying to accomplish, or what you've done to get to the place where you are now.  Just posting code and an error message often isn't enough debugging for folks to understand what's going on.  We need enough information to be able to reproduce the issue ourselves.

Answer (score 6):

Using @babel/polyfill is officially deprecated. Since you are using a react application (and do not rely on a legacy codebase) you could prefer using the following:

```
npm i --save core-js/stable regenerator-runtime
```

```
// ECMA Script Polyfills:
import "core-js/stable";
// Needed for the generator functions which are transpiled from your async await keywords
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";
```

[Reference](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill)

Comment: A variant of this worked for me: npm i --save-dev regenerator-runtime (the full command you listed was giving git errors - I think the repositories have been removed?)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know @eAi, I checked it and updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

npm install --save @babel/polyfill might be the solution and also import them into your file.

Comment: It worked wow. May I ask why is that needed?